# Execute a JQuery function according to name of html element's ID

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a web page in which there are 3 elements and each has their ID, in script section I have 3 functions with same names as html ID has.. I want to execute the respective function on click of element.. following is my code:([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/LfAs2/))

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="btn">
  Click here for 1
</div>
<div id="two" class="btn">
  Click Here for 2
</div>
<div id="three" class="btn">
  Click Here for 3
</div>
```

JQ:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
  $(this).attr('id')()  //here I want to run function
});
function one(){alert("one clicked")}
function two(){alert("two clicked")}
function three(){alert("three clicked")}
```

Please help.. I don't wanna use if statement ... I'm trying to do this in most optimized way.. :)
Here is the link of [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/LfAs2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other way using window global object:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfAs2/3/)

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
      window[this.id]();  //here I want to run function            
});
one = function(){alert("one clicked")}
two = function(){alert("two clicked")}
three = function(){alert("three clicked")}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to declare the functions (1, 2 and 3) FIRST and THEN call them? Am I wrong?

Comment: @NDLombardi you are right but here, as functions are called inside a click handler it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 10):

Define the functions as an object like below,

```
var myFunc = {
  one: function (){alert("one clicked")},
  two: function (){alert("two clicked")},
  three: function (){alert("three clicked")}
};
```

Now call inside the handler as,

```
myFunc[this.id](); //Note: this.id is good and better than $(this).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this:

```
var theFunctions = {
      one: function () { alert("one clicked"); },
      two: function () { alert("two clicked"); },
      three: function () { alert("three clicked"); },
};

$('.btn').on('click',function(){
   theFunctions[$(this).attr('id')](); //here I want to run function
});
```

You can check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/RFANE/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval($(this).attr('id'));
```

NOTE: Before using this method you need to read about [eval](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/).

Comment: Thanks for at least acknowledging that `eval` is bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
    eval($(this).attr('id'))();
});
```

Comment: Really?  `eval`.  You *could* do this, but I would suggest against it.

Comment: I agree with you, but in some case, if you really trust the source, you can use the `eval`